# Numerus in »das sind« und »es gibt«

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Warum sagt man:

> Das **sind** Fußballfans.

aber:

> Es **gibt** Fußballfans.

Gibt es eine Regel dafür? Als Nicht­mut­ter­sprach­ler würde ich sagen:

> Das **ist** Fußballfans.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Betrachten wir einmal die Fälle in den beiden Sätzen:

> Das (=Nominativ) **sind** Fußballfans (=Nominativ).
> Es (=Nominativ) **gibt** Fußballfans (=Akkusativ).

### *Sein* mit Nominativ-Objekt:

Das Verb ***sein*** setzt hier zwei Dinge gleich; beide stehen im Nominativ, weshalb man vom sogenannten [Gleichsetzungsnominativ](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Subjekt-11481) spricht. Dieser Link stammt von canoo.net, wo zu lesen ist:

> Wenn Subjekt und Gleichsetzungsnominativ in einem Satz nicht den gleichen Numerus haben, steht das finite Verb in der Regel im Plural:
>
> > Mein größter Besitz sind meine Kinder.
> > [...]
> > Das sind meine Schuhe.

Dies ist in deinem ersten Beispielsatz der Fall: Das Pronomen *das* steht im Singular, der Gleichsetzungsnominativ *Fußballfans* steht im Plural; also steht das Verb *sein* auch im Plural.

### *Geben* mit Akkusativ-Objekt:

In deinem zweiten Satz gibt es so einen Gleichsetzungsnominativ nicht. Das Verb ***geben*** verlangt kein Nominativ-Objekt, sondern ein Akkusativ-Objekt, sodass sich der Numerus des Verbs nur nach dem Subjekt richtet. Das Subjekt ist hier *es*, ein Singular-Pronomen, sodass auch das Verb im Singular stehen muss - und zwar unabhängig davon, ob das Objekt im Singular oder im Plural steht:

> Es **gibt** Fußballfans (=Plural).
> Es **gibt** Suppe (=Singular).

Comment: Vielleicht solltest du noch ein Singular-Beispiel zu *es gibt* ergänzen (Vorschlag: *Es gibt Suppe.*) macht die Sache anschaulicher.